# Why am I getting these linker errors with cinder and CodeBlocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks, linker-errors, clang++, cinder

I'm having a bit of trouble compiling a project of mine using Code::Blocks and llvm-clang on Windows 10. Here's some of the error msg as its waay too long to fit in fully, but all of what should be needed is in there.

```
clang++.exe -LC:\Qub3d\cinder_master\lib -o bin\Debug\Qub3d.exe obj\Debug\src\mainMenus\mainMenu.o obj\Debug\src\Qub3d_EngineApp.o   ..\Qub3d-libs\lib\msw\x64\libEGL.lib ..\Qub3d-libs\lib\msw\x64\libGLESv2.lib ..\Qub3d-libs\lib\msw\x64\libpng.lib ..\Qub3d-libs\lib\msw\x64\Debug\v141\cinder.lib
cinder.lib(wrapper.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in mainMenu.o
cinder.lib(GlslProg.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in mainMenu.o
cinder.lib(GlslProg.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in mainMenu.
libcpmtd.lib(stdthrow.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value '2' doesn't match value '0' in mainMenu.o
libcpmtd.lib(stdthrow.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MTd_StaticDebug' doesn't match value 'MT_StaticRelease' in mainMenu.o
LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'LIBCMTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
mainMenu.o : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol __std_terminate imported in function "int `public: __cdecl std::shared_ptr<class cinder::app::Window>::~shared_ptr<class cinder::app::Window>(void)'::`1'::dtor$2" (?dtor$2@?0???1?$shared_ptr@VWindow@app@cinder@@@std@@QEAA@XZ@4HA)
Qub3d_EngineApp.o : warning LNK4049: locally defined symbol __std_terminate imported
Qub3d_EngineApp.o : warning LNK4217: locally defined symbol _CxxThrowException imported in function "int `private: void __cdecl std::shared_ptr<class cinder::app::Renderer>::_Setp<class cinder::app::RendererGl>(class cinder::app::RendererGl *,struct shared_ptr<class cinder::app::Renderer>::integral_constant<bool,0>)'::`1'::catch$4" (?catch$4@?0???$_Setp@VRendererGl@app@cinder@@@?$shared_ptr@VRenderer@app@cinder@@@std@@AEAAXPEAVRendererGl@app@cinder@@U?$integral_constant@_N$0A@@1@@Z@4HA)
cinder.lib(TextureFormatParsers.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReportW
cinder.lib(Unicode.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReportW
cinder.lib(RendererImplGlMsw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReportW
cinder.lib(Platform.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReportW
cinder.lib(Signals.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReportW
cinder.lib(System.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReportW
cinder.lib(Context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReportW
cinder.lib(Batch.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReportW
cinder.lib(Log.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReportW
cinder.lib(Exception.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReportW
cinder.lib(Window.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReportW
cinder.lib(Environment.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReportW
cinder.lib(CinderAssert.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReportW
cinder.lib(Shader.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReportW
cinder.lib(wrapper.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReportW
cinder.lib(RendererGl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReportW
cinder.lib(AppBase.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReportW
cinder.lib(AppMsw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReportW
cinder.lib(AppMsw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetCursorPos referenced in function "public: virtual struct glm::tvec2<int,0> __cdecl cinder::app::AppMsw::getMousePos(void)const " (?getMousePos@AppMsw@app@cinder@@UEBA?AU?$tvec2@H$0A@@glm@@XZ)
cinder.lib(AppMsw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CommandLineToArgvW referenced in function "public: static void __cdecl cinder::app::AppMsw::initialize(class cinder::app::AppMsw::Settings *,class std::shared_ptr<class cinder::app::Renderer> const &,char const *)" (?initialize@AppMsw@app@cinder@@SAXPEAVSettings@123@AEBV?$shared_ptr@VRenderer@app@cinder@@@std@@PEBD@Z)
cinder.lib(ConstantConversions.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _calloc_dbg
cinder.lib(PlatformMsw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _free_dbg
cinder.lib(GeomIo.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _free_dbg
cinder.lib(GlslProg.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _free_dbg
cinder.lib(BufferObj.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _free_dbg
cinder.lib(Vao.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _free_dbg
cinder.lib(Fbo.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _free_dbg
cinder.lib(Context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _free_dbg
cinder.lib(Log.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _free_dbg
cinder.lib(Utilities.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _free_dbg
cinder.lib(Texture.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _free_dbg
cinder.lib(ShaderPreprocessor.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _malloc_dbg
cinder.lib(ConstantConversions.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _malloc_dbg
cinder.lib(VboMesh.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _malloc_dbg
cinder.lib(PlatformMsw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _malloc_dbg
cinder.lib(GeomIo.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _malloc_dbg
cinder.lib(GlslProg.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _malloc_dbg
cinder.lib(BufferObj.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _malloc_dbg
cinder.lib(Vao.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _malloc_dbg
cinder.lib(Fbo.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _malloc_dbg
cinder.lib(Context.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _malloc_dbg
cinder.lib(Log.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _malloc_dbg
cinder.lib(Utilities.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _malloc_dbg
cinder.lib(Texture.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _malloc_dbg
cinder.lib(Log.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CloseEventLog referenced in function "public: virtual __cdecl cinder::log::LoggerSystem::ImplEventLog::~ImplEventLog(void)" (??1ImplEventLog@LoggerSystem@log@cinder@@UEAA@XZ)
cinder.lib(Log.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RegisterEventSourceW referenced in function "public: __cdecl cinder::log::LoggerSystem::ImplEventLog::ImplEventLog(void)" (??0ImplEventLog@LoggerSystem@log@cinder@@QEAA@XZ)
cinder.lib(Log.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ReportEventW referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl cinder::log::LoggerSystem::ImplEventLog::write(struct cinder::log::Metadata const &,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?write@ImplEventLog@LoggerSystem@log@cinder@@UEAAXAEBUMetadata@34@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
cinder.lib(RendererImplGlMsw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ChoosePixelFormat referenced in function "bool __cdecl cinder::app::`anonymous namespace'::getWglFunctionPointers(struct HGLRC__ * (__cdecl**)(struct HDC__ *,struct HGLRC__ *,int const *),int (__cdecl**)(struct HDC__ *,int const *,float const *,unsigned int,int *,unsigned int *))" (?getWglFunctionPointers@?A0x83b54a9b@app@cinder@@YA_NPEAP6APEAUHGLRC__@@PEAUHDC__@@PEAU4@PEBH@ZPEAP6AH02PEBMIPEAHPEAI@Z@Z)
cinder.lib(RendererImplGlMsw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DescribePixelFormat referenced in function "bool __cdecl cinder::app::`anonymous namespace'::setPixelFormat(struct HDC__ *,struct cinder::app::RendererGl::Options const &)" (?setPixelFormat@?A0x83b54a9b@app@cinder@@YA_NPEAUHDC__@@AEBUOptions@RendererGl@23@@Z)
cinder.lib(RendererImplGlMsw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetPixelFormat referenced in function "bool __cdecl cinder::app::`anonymous namespace'::getWglFunctionPointers(struct HGLRC__ * (__cdecl**)(struct HDC__ *,struct HGLRC__ *,int const *),int (__cdecl**)(struct HDC__ *,int const *,float const *,unsigned int,int *,unsigned int *))" (?getWglFunctionPointers@?A0x83b54a9b@app@cinder@@YA_NPEAP6APEAUHGLRC__@@PEAUHDC__@@PEAU4@PEBH@ZPEAP6AH02PEBMIPEAHPEAI@Z@Z)
cinder.lib(RendererImplGlMsw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SwapBuffers referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl cinder::app::RendererImplGlMsw::swapBuffers(void)const " (?swapBuffers@RendererImplGlMsw@app@cinder@@UEBAXXZ)
cinder.lib(RendererImplGlMsw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_DefWindowProcW referenced in function "struct HWND__ * __cdecl cinder::app::`anonymous namespace'::createDummyWindow(void)" (?createDummyWindow@?A0x83b54a9b@app@cinder@@YAPEAUHWND__@@XZ)
cinder.lib(AppImplMsw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_DefWindowProcW
cinder.lib(RendererImplGlMsw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RegisterClassW referenced in function "struct HWND__ * __cdecl cinder::app::`anonymous namespace'::createDummyWindow(void)" (?createDummyWindow@?A0x83b54a9b@app@cinder@@YAPEAUHWND__@@XZ)
cinder.lib(AppImplMsw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_MapVirtualKeyW referenced in function "wchar_t __cdecl cinder::app::mapVirtualKey(unsigned __int64)" (?mapVirtualKey@app@cinder@@YA_W_K@Z)
cinder.lib(AppImplMsw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetCapture referenced in function "__int64 __cdecl cinder::app::WndProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned __int64,__int64)" (?WndProc@app@cinder@@YA_JPEAUHWND__@@I_K_J@Z)
cinder.lib(AppImplMsw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_ReleaseCapture referenced in function "__int64 __cdecl cinder::app::WndProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned __int64,__int64)" (?WndProc@app@cinder@@YA_JPEAUHWND__@@I_K_J@Z)
cinder.lib(AppImplMsw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetForegroundWindow referenced in function "public: __cdecl cinder::app::BlankingWindow::BlankingWindow(class std::shared_ptr<class cinder::Display>)" (??0BlankingWindow@app@cinder@@QEAA@V?$shared_ptr@VDisplay@cinder@@@std@@@Z)
cinder.lib(AppImplMsw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_BeginPaint referenced in function "__int64 __cdecl cinder::app::BlankingWndProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned __int64,__int64)" (?BlankingWndProc@app@cinder@@YA_JPEAUHWND__@@I_K_J@Z)
cinder.lib(RendererImpl2dGdi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_BeginPaint
cinder.lib(AppImplMsw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_EndPaint referenced in function "__int64 __cdecl cinder::app::BlankingWndProc(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned __int64,__int64)" (?BlankingWndProc@app@cinder@@YA_JPEAUHWND__@@I_K_J@Z)
cinder.lib(RendererImpl2dGdi.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_EndPaint
cinder.lib(AppImplMsw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_InvalidateRect referenced in function "public: void __cdecl cinder::app::WindowImplMsw::setBorderless(bool)" (?setBorderless@WindowImplMsw@app@cinder@@QEAAX_N@Z)
cinder.lib(AppImplMsw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_RedrawWindow referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl cinder::app::WindowImplMsw::redraw(void)" (?redraw@WindowImplMsw@app@cinder@@UEAAXXZ)
cinder.lib(AppImplMsw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_SetWindowTextW referenced in function "public: virtual void __cdecl cinder::app::WindowImplMsw::setTitle(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (?setTitle@WindowImplMsw@app@cinder@@UEAAXAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)
cinder.lib(AppImplMsw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetWindowTextW referenced in function "public: virtual class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __cdecl cinder::app::WindowImplMsw::getTitle(void)const " (?getTitle@WindowImplMsw@app@cinder@@UEBA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ)
cinder.lib(AppImplMsw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetOpenFileNameW referenced in function "public: static class std::experimental::filesystem::v1::path __cdecl cinder::app::AppImplMsw::getOpenFilePath(class std::experimental::filesystem::v1::path const &,class std::vector<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > >)" (?getOpenFilePath@AppImplMsw@app@cinder@@SA?AVpath@v1@filesystem@experimental@std@@AEBV45678@V?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@8@@Z)
cinder.lib(AppImplMsw.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_GetSaveFileNameW referenced in function "public: static class std::experimental::filesystem::v1::path __cdecl cinder::app::AppImplMsw::getSaveFilePath(class std::experimental::filesystem::v1::path const &,class std::vector<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > >)" (?getSaveFilePath@AppImplMsw@app@cinder@@SA?AVpath@v1@filesystem@experimental@std@@AEBV45678@V?$vector@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@8@@Z)
cinder.lib(ImageTargetFileWic.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol __imp_CoCreateInstance
cinder.lib(ImageTargetFileWic.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_VariantInit referenced in function "protected: __cdecl cinder::ImageTargetFileWic::ImageTargetFileWic(class std::shared_ptr<class cinder::DataTarget>,class std::shared_ptr<class cinder::ImageSource>,class cinder::ImageTarget::Options,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (??0ImageTargetFileWic@cinder@@IEAA@V?$shared_ptr@VDataTarget@cinder@@@std@@V?$shared_ptr@VImageSource@cinder@@@3@VOptions@ImageTarget@1@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@3@@Z)
bin\Debug\Qub3d.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 93 unresolved externals
```

I've linked cinder.lib, libEGL.lib, libGLESv2.lib, and libpng.lib
I don't see any reason why this should not be working.

Comment: This looks interesting to me. Looks like Visual Studio linker errors but clang is used. I don't use clang so not sure if that is expected. Also some of the errors look very much like Microsoft errors complaining about the mixing of Debug and Release in the same application. Yet some of the files are .o and others are .obj.

Comment: Funny thing is that I can compile this on MSVC, but i want to use clang for cross-compatibility purposes.